# Can I group a set of related systemd service files into a common directory under `/etc/systemd/system`?

Tags: linux, systemd

The usual directory to place systemd unit files is

```
/etc/systemd/system/
```

It contains a number of service files by default.

If I have a number of related service files which are all part of the same application system, can I create a subdirectory at this location to group them into a single folder?

For example, if I have three processes managed by systemd:

```
process1.service
process2.service
process3.service
```

is there a way to use those service files if I put them inside a directory

```
/etc/systemd/system/group_of_processes/
```

If I run `systemctl daemon-reload` the service files don't appear to be picked up if they are under a subdirectory `group_of_processes`.

Comment: Give us an example and explain what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @aviro Does the additional edit help?

Comment: @aviro I don't think that's the same thing. I don't want to bring the group up and down together. I still want to be able to control each service independently. Does that mean what I am trying to do is not possible?

Comment: So why do you want them to reside at the same directory?

Comment: @aviro So I can easily delete them as a group

Comment: And why would you want to do that? What purpose does it serve? Why does it bother you they are there if they're stopped and disabled? Or why can't you just track them with links to another folder or something like that?